# ProxyPass and RewriteRule make pages lose style

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat

I'm setting up a apache with a

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.myhost.com [P]
```

It already works, but the page that is displayed only contains text. Images, styles etc are all lost. What am I missing here?

If I manually go to myhost.com it works of course as expected.

Comment: Where's the rule set?  What are the URLs of the resources are failing, and how are they linked in the HTML of the loaded page?  What response codes are you getting for those resources?

Comment: The URL is myhomemachine/manager:8080. If I access my proxy, it is redirecting by RewriteRule. I don't have any "ruleset". Now, I only get the text from the apache server test site. Any styles or images are lost.

Comment: 1) That URL is not using port 8080, it's using 80.  Change to `http://myhomemachine:8080/manager`.  2) By "Where's the rule set", I mean: what file and where in the file is your `RewriteRule` located? 3) Can you use your browser's debugging tools to provide more information about what's happening when the resources are failing to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append the path to the destination URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myhost.com/$1 [P]
```

(And, by the way, there's a slash missing in the URL.)

Comment: MIssing slash was just a type, thnx. No I do not want to append anything to my destination url. I just want to call myhost.com, which displays a webpage. Regardless of what is entered to access my ReverseProxy...  And the new page now looses all styles.

Comment: That means that you also rewrite styles such as `domain.com/style.css` to `www.myhost.com`. This is exactly why you lose the styles.

Comment: Hm how can I prevent this? I just want the new page to be proxied through as it is. But the user should not be aware of this, that's why I'm doing the ProxyPass [P].

Comment: You need to also proxy the css files and images that are needed to show the page. This is for example done with the rule that is in my answer.

Comment: With your rule I'm just getting a 404 could not be found. Eg: If I go to localhost/test, then te remapping takes place to: myhost.com/test. which results in 404, because "test" does not exist on myhost server. And I do not want to display test, just myhost.com with all its content.

Comment: OK, I have edited the regex, can you try again?

Comment: no does not work either...

Answer (score 1):

Oliver answer is just fine: but remember also that, even if you're apparently using mod_rewrite, when using the [P] modifier, it's mod_proxy which is doing the actual work. So you should also add the "ProxyPassReverse" directive, like this:

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.myhost.com/ [P]
```

See [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) for references.

Comment: I'm using a reference to a txt file within my RewriteRule. Did not show this here as it would only cause more confusion. So I cannot use ProxyPassReverse with this txt file. Or could I somehow?